# Как сделать чтобы вставлялось значение в message.args[3]?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Как сделать чтобы в mongoose значение message.args[3] вставлялось в данный код:

```
users.updateOne({uid: Number(message.args[2])}, {$set: {"${message.args[3]}": (message.args[4])}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вставить собственное значение в updateOne:    `users.updateOne({uid: Number(message.args[2])}, {$set: {[message.args[3]]: (message.args[4])}});`